# How to move text left and right in command line? [ASM]

Tags: assembly, command-line, terminal, console, tasm

I'm learning to use assembly language, and one of my tasks is to write an application that will draw a square and move it in some direction when user presses an arrow key.

I use tasm and I found some functions that can help me with moving it up and down by scrolling command line window (`06h` and `07h` of `10h`'th interruption) but I didn't find any that allow to do same thing moving it left and right.

Does anybody know a solution for the problem? Maybe there is a way to insert/remove spaces around my square?

The square is not a manipulation with background color, but a set of strings like this:

```
*****
*   *
*****
```

Answer (score 0):

It's probably not a good idea to use BIOS functions 06h/07h to achieve this functionality!
Consider this: If you can draw the image (square) then you can draw it again and again and again. The trick is to first redraw it with an attribute of say BlackOnBlack to make it disappear and then redraw it in the actual colors at the new location based on the user's keyboard input.

Comment: Seems like I've explained the problem not clear enough, sorry. The sqare is made of '*' symbols, so it is a set of strings, not the background color as you may thought. That's why i choose these functions.

Comment: Then just replace **an attribute of say BlackOnBlack** with **a character code of 20h (space)**. The methodology is the same.

Comment: What 70 is trying to say is that since there (apparently) is no bios function to do this, you are going to have to simulate it.  To perform the "move", you'll need to do 2 things: 1) Erase the box at the old position. 2) Draw the box at the new position.  When he's talking about drawing spaces or playing with attributes, he's trying to tell you ways to erase the old box.

Comment: I'll take a stab at explaining it:  Pick a point, that's your starting place. Draw he square. The user presses a button. Check to make sure there is space (e.g., that the user hasn't gone past the edge of the available screen). Once you are confident that there is space then, re-draw the same square with space characters (i.e. '` `' which is usually 020h) and move the cursor to the new starting point. From this new starting point, repeat the entire process